# VPN Connection using Genymotion Emulator

Tags: vpn

I am trying to execute an application in my Genymotion emulator. The problem is that I need to be connected to VPN Connection for test my application, but Genymotion doesn't work when I connect VPN. Is possible execute an application in Genymotion staying connected to WiFi and VPN in the laptop?